# ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range sometimes returns table's AutoFilter based on selected cell

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

Edit: The best I can do is to find the last used cell and then offset it by one row and one column. This will fail if the user is using the entire sheet, but I'm willing to take that chance. I can select this cell temporarily and then switch back to the user's previous cell.

```
Public Function getCellOutsideUsedRange(ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = getLastCellOnSheet(ws)
    If rng.Row = ws.Rows.CountLarge Then
        If rng.Column = ws.Columns.CountLarge Then
            Set getCellOutsideUsedRange = Nothing
        Else
            Set getCellOutsideUsedRange = rng.offset(0, 1)
        End If
    ElseIf rng.Column = ws.Columns.CountLarge Then
        If rng.Row = ws.Rows.CountLarge Then
            Set getCellOutsideUsedRange = Nothing
        Else
            Set getCellOutsideUsedRange = rng.offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Else
        Set getCellOutsideUsedRange = rng.offset(1, 1)
    End If
End Function

Public Function getLastCellOnSheet(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Set getLastCellOnSheet = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
End Function
```

---

If you have a cell  selected inside a table, ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range returns the autofilter applied to the table, not the worksheet. Example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim af As AutoFilter

    Range("C1").Select
    Set af = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter
    MsgBox af.Range(1).Value2
    MsgBox af.Parent.Name

    Range("C12").Select
    Set af = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter
    MsgBox af.Range(1).Value2
    MsgBox af.Parent.Name

End Sub
```

[image]

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/autofilter-range-property-excel) doesn't really help me. How can I ensure that I can get to the sheet autofilter, even if the user happens to have a cell selected in a table, without having to cycle through cells until I get one outside a table?

Context: I have a short macro that returns a list of all the filters that have been applied to the sheet. In summary, it looks through the worksheet and any tables and, for each, uses the AutoFilter.Range property to get the range that is filtered, selects the top row of this range to get the filter headings, and then checks each cell in the filter headings for any criteria. If a user has a cell selected in a table, they won't get back any worksheet filters.

Comment: Do you have an *AutoFilter* and a *Table* in the same worksheet??

Comment: Yes, possibly. Sometimes a user may be using the autofilter, but have separate tables for lookup purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In general, using `Select` in VBA and depending on it is a bad practice. [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Concerning the AutoFilters - you are allowed to have only one AutoFilter per worksheet, which is outside a table. Thus, it is accessible through `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range`, which could be `Nothing` or `Not Nothing`.

Concerning the autofilters in the tables, you may simply loop through the tables and check one by one whether the AutoFilter is there or not:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim cntAutoFilters      As Long
    Dim cnt                 As Long
    Dim wks                 As Worksheet
    Dim tbl                 As ListObject

    Set wks = Worksheets(1)

    If Not wks.AutoFilter.Range Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print wks.AutoFilter.Range.Address
    End If

    For Each tbl In wks.ListObjects
        If Not tbl.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print tbl.Range.Address
        End If
    Next tbl

End Sub
```

Concerning the MSDN documentation:

- [`AutoFilter.Range` is a property of AutoFilter.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/autofilter-range-property-excel)
- [`Range.AutoFilter` is a method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel)

**Edit:**
It really seems that if you have a cell selected within a table in a worksheet, then the AutoFilter outside this table somehow cannot be referred.

Comment: Hi - using ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range doesn't access the sheet's autofilter if the cell you have selected is inside a table. That's why I used the Select statements in my example. Your TestMe() runs into the same problem.

Comment: @Jonathan - yup, this seems to be true.